# Is there a proper folder structure guideline for multi role react redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a CRA(Not ejected) react-redux application that has 5 roles, Admin, B2B, school, etc. Does following folder structure make sense ?

```
action
  admin
  B2B
  school
components
  admin
  B2B
  school
reducers
  admin
  B2B
  school
pages
  admin
  B2B
  school
```

Any alternate approach/suggestions will be really helpful .

Answer (score 0):

It really depend of the size of the project. There is no "silver bullet" architecture so everything can work

The main idea is to see how you can reuse component (so maybe you will also have a shared/common folder for reusable component - I see you have a component folder which do that). You can also check some articles about "atomic design", it can be helpful on how to split a big project into reusable component with "atoms, molecule...".

Also your routing can have some impact on how you want to split your application.

But from what I see you already splited your code into different categories based on the logic which is great. It seems to be a good start and maybe you will see some issue while building your project and change some stuff.